# Automount NFS shared home directories and other shares

Tags: macos, automount, autofs

I have a problem with autofs on mac. I made some shares:

`auto_home`:

```
*   -fstype=nfs,rw  roskilde:/space/home/&
```

`auto_remote`:

```
public  -fstype=nfs,rw  roskilde:/space/public
mosek   -fstype=nfs,rw  roskilde:/space/mosek
vmware  -fstype=nfs,rw  roskilde:/space/vmware
```

`auto_master`:

```
+auto_master        # Use directory service
/net            -hosts      -nobrowse,hidefromfinder,nosuid
/home           auto_home   
/remote         auto_remote
/Network/Servers    -fstab
/-          -static
```

so the problem is this. The shares mount fine, I think, but the problem is that everything mount with permissions like this:

```
dr-xr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  1 Nov 20 14:30 andrea
dr-xr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  1 Nov 20 14:30 eda
dr-xr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  1 Nov 20 14:30 hap
dr-xr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  1 Nov 20 14:30 joachim
dr-xr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  1 Nov 20 14:30 ruben
dr-xr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  1 Nov 20 14:30 sandvik
dr-xr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  1 Nov 20 14:30 tomas
dr-xr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  1 Nov 20 14:30 ulfw
```

where the owner should be `username:users`

when I try logging into the server:

```
$ ssh tomas@lyngby
Password:
Could not chdir to home directory /home/tomas: Operation not permitted
-bash: /home/tomas/.bash_profile: Operation not permitted
lyngby:/ tomas$ cd /home/tomas/
-bash: cd: /home/tomas/: Operation not permitted
```

What causes this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: I've never worked with this on the Mac side, but presuming that it functions similarly to `fstab`, your mount instruction parameters have to specify ownership and permissions if you want that functionality. Otherwise, mount points will always be owned by `root` as the `automount` process is run through it.

Comment: in `fstab` how do you specify the ownership and permissions of a mount? `fstab` and `automount` are very similar, so maybe I can use the info

Comment: I would start reading here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man5/auto_master.5.html in conjunction with Google searching to construct your mounts with correct permissions. Also you might have to check the system you're mounting the directories from to see if it will allow NFS exports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem was very simple to fix. Just add the resvport option to all the mounting point, and if works like a charm